# Passing a drawn graphic

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I'm trying to pass a graphics element up the chain. I need to have the ability to draw a number of different die and return the correct one for each instance. I can get this to compile but I don't know if i'm doing this correctly. I want to pass the graphics component to a panel to be displayed.

My shortened paint class

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;


class DiePaint extends JPanel
{
Graphics g;

public Graphics dieSwitch(int inInt)
{
    return die1();
}
private Graphics die1()
{
    //reset drawing
    repaint();

    //draw a die with 1 pip
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
    g.drawOval(24,24,2,2);
    g.fillOval(24,24,2,2);

    //return graphic
    return g;
}
```

}

A method in my other class i'm trying to use to call it.

```
private void setDie()
{
    //set die labels
    die1P.paint(drawDie.dieSwitch(game.getDie(0)));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry but I can't follow what you are trying to do, neither in the description nor in the code. All I can say is that you shouldn't call panel.paint(), but panel.repaint() and override the paintComponent(Graphics g) method in that panel. The paintComponent will be supplied by Swing with the appropriate Graphics object. A Graphics object for a JComponent (such as a JPanel) is not something you store and reuse.

Comment: I'm trying to get the dice to show in the top most panel and i want then to be drawn from a seperate class so i can simply call a method to have them drawn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "I want to pass the graphics component to a panel to be displayed."

No, you *don't*.

You need to see how to [Perform Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html).  You're going to need a `paintComponent` method in your panel

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphic s) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // draw here
}
```

You don't explicitly call `paint` like you are doing here `die1P.paint(drawDie.dieSwitch`

If you want to be able to set what is being painted, you can have a `Die` object that you use to draw. Something like

```
class Die {
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // draw die here
    }
}
```

Then in your panel class have a `setter` for the `Die` object, that will repaint the new `Die`. You will probably want to have a way to differentiate each die. Pass some arguments to a constructor to do that. Then paint the *one* die.

```
public class DiePanel extends JPanel {
    private Die die;
    public void setDie(Die die) {
        this.die = die;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (die != null) {
            die.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

You may also, instead, want to make `Die` an interface, so you can implement difference `Die` objects, like `DieOne`, `DieTwo`, etc. Something like

```
public interface Die {
    void Draw(Grapchis g);
}

public class DieOne {
    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {
        // draw die one
    }
}
```

When you call `setDie()`, you can pass a specific `Die`, like

```
DieOne dieOne = new DieOne();
...
diePanel.setDie(dieOne);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can pass the drawn component by using BufferedImage....first you draw the graphic on this BufferedImage then pass this image and then draw this image to the Panel...Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.image.*;


class DiePaint extends JPanel
{
int width=500; int height=500;  //you can change as requred
BufferedImage buffg=new BufferedImage(width,height , BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics g;

public BufferedImage dieSwitch(int inInt)   //change return type to BufferedImage
{
    return die1();
}
private BufferedImage die1()     // change return type to BufferedImage
{
    g=buffg.getGraphics();   //get Graphics from buffg..
    //reset drawing
    repaint();

    //draw a die with 1 pip   
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);   //draw all the component on buffg using its Graphics g
    g.drawRect(0,0,50,50);
    g.drawOval(24,24,2,2);
    g.fillOval(24,24,2,2);

    //return graphic
    return buffg;
}
}
```

now once you get this "buffg" now you can draw it on any panel.....

```
JPanel p=new JPanel(){
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g){
         g.drawImage(drawDie.dieSwitch(game.getDie(0)));   //get & draw Image
    }

};
```